# When asked to find a coterminal angle, can you combine radians and degrees?

Tags: trigonometry

Upon creating a recent exam, a colleague of mine told me that he would accept the answer $\frac{\pi}{5}$+360$^{\circ}$ as a positive coterminal angle to $\frac{\pi}{5}$. I disagreed and said that you cannot combine radians and degrees without conversion (and also that $\frac{\pi}{5}$+360$^{\circ}$ is not an angle). He says that is just semantics and that 360$^{\circ}$  is in fact, 2${\pi}$. Who is right?

Comment: IMHO, technically correct but a really really really bad idea.

Comment: on a scale of thumbs down to 2π, how bad of an idea? @David

Comment: Approximately $6.28$ thumbs down :)

Comment: Disregard the ideas of anyone who says "it's just semantics". "Semantics" means meaning: so someone who dismisses semantics is telling you that they don't care what things mean.

Comment: Rob, I agree. I thought that was the point. I suppose it made me think, "What is the purpose of posing this problem?". And the answer to that was that I wanted my students to be able to find multiple solutions to equations involving trig on intervals not exclusive to [0, 2${\pi}$]. The semantics here are pretty important, no? I wonder how I should have phrased the question to be more precise?

Comment: The ISO seems to agree with your colleague, they say the degree symbol is just a numeric factor.

Comment: David, can you link to that?

Comment: @Nikki I don't have access the relevant ISO documents, but I recall this argument being made by someone who referred to the documents (and I believed they were truthful about what the ISO wrote). I though this was on MSE but unfortunately I can not find it now. But https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168538 says "radian" is just a name for the number 1 according to ISO, and a degree is $\pi/180$ rad, so ...

Comment: *exam* is the keyword here.  How unfair would it be to reject an answer like this ?  It seems very hard as there's nothing really technically wrong with it.  If the marks denied someone for this type of answer stopped them gaining e.g. a higher overall grade on their course it would be cruel.  Let it slide.  Cut people some slack.

Comment: Cruel may be over reaching. There is actually no use for an angle written in this form. I suppose we can question why we bother simplifying anything at all.

Comment: @StephenG Perfectly fair.  The purpose of an exam is not merely to elicit "technically correct" answers, but to judge how well the examinee understands a subject.  Would you give full marks to someone who was asked to solve $x^2=4$ and gave the answer$$\frac{-0\pm\sqrt{0^2-4(1)(-4)}}{2(1)}\ ?$$I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: @David So you are going to punish someone for what ?  Not writing down a single exact numerical answer (utterly pointless in general and impossible in others) ?  Or not apply the method *you* expected ?  I see no issue here worth punishing someone for.  Would you have punished someone for claiming $\sum_k^\infty k = -1/12$ ?  Because at one time that was considered nonsense.  You are, IMO, suggesting punishing someone for thinking *differently* which is not, I would say, a good idea.

Comment: @StephenG I don't really feel like replying to that comment when you use ridiculous, loaded terms like "punish".  But anyway.  The point is very simple: good answers deserve good marks, more-or-less good answers deserve more-or-less good marks, and bad answers deserve bad marks.  The merit of an answer is **not** determined solely by the accuracy of the final numerical calculation.

Comment: @David "he point is very simple: good answers deserve good marks..."  The point I was making (which either you are ignoring deliberately or don't get) is that "good answer" is a term in the eye of the beholder.  The example you gave could easily be argued to be a demonstration by the student that they know a more general form for the equation and understand how to get it's roots.  What's wrong with them doing that ?  Why should they loose *any* marks for that ?

Comment: @StephenG "either you are ignoring deliberately" - now you're just trolling, and I'm not interested.  Goodbye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't think the answer is *teeeeechnically* wrong, it is absolutely improper to combine two uncompatible units as such. You don't tell people that they are $5$ feet and $22$ centimeters tall. I would not award credit -- and I think a reasonable expectation of students that could even arrive at an answer of $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{5}$ for any question is that they know that $2\pi$ is the same angle as $360º$. You are in the right, and it is important to instill mathematical clarity in students.

Comment: How could I rephrase the question so that there is no ambiguity at all? The original problem was: State a positive coterminal angle to $\frac{\pi}{5}$  .

Comment: Answers must be stated in radians. or, communicate to your students that only one set of units can be used in general, and maintain that expectation in the future; that's easier

Comment: Thank you Saketh. I will be sure to change my wording for future assignments. By the by, would a combo unit answer be acceptable in real world situations using angles, or am I totally overthinking this? I really try to teach my students to be precise and I hate to think I would be overemphasizing a skill that is outdated or useless when used in real life.

Comment: I really don't think so! This is mostly something about keeping up with accepted "norms." just as how we don't use customary and metric units together (in the real world), we would not use radians and degrees together in math, and i think it would raise eyebrows if people were to hear it outside

Answer (score 1):

I would say you colleague is right (but it's not 100% clear) since it is only a matter of unit. For instance take $\varphi$ and $\theta$ two angles, the sum $\varphi+\theta$ is well defined as an angle, now suppose $\varphi=\frac{\pi}{5}rad$ and $\theta=360^{\circ}$, you can still write $\frac{\pi}{5}+360^{\circ}$ since it a sum of two angles, regardless the way you write them. For example you can add 1 hour and 30 minutes : $1h+30min=1h30min$, same thing.

Comment: hours and minutes are regularly used in conjunction with one another; radians and degrees are not; just as inches and centimeters wouldn't be used in the same measurement

Comment: It is worse than 1 h + 30 min.   More like: 25 feet + 3 meters.

Comment: Yes, in fact you can't say it is totally wrong despite the fact it is very rarely written as $\frac{\pi}{5}+360^{\circ}$, much more than $1h+30min=1h30min$ is.

Comment: I agree, that it is not totally wrong, however, is there ever any time when we would actually use  $\frac{\pi}{5}+360$^{\circ}$ ?

Comment: I hope you will never have to meet this notation.

Comment: Ha ha, yes, for some reason I can not get my degree symbol to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with you. Degrees and Radians are two different measures for angles. They can be converted from one to another but it is wrong to add them up. Let's consider a different example, if you have a binary number 110011 then you can not add a decimal number 50 to that binary number. You just have to convert one to the other system before any mathematical operation.

I would say $\frac{\pi}{5}+360^{\circ}$ is not the coterminal angle for $\frac{\pi}{5}$.

Comment: What's wrong with $110011_2 + 50$ (aside from inconvenience of having to do the base conversion to actually get an answer)? Or $1\ \mathrm{km} + 10\ \mathrm{cm}$? I do not like $\frac\pi5 + 360^\circ$, but is that just my opinion or is it certainly an error to add angles that way?

Comment: @DavidK So far I know, a coterminal angle is a an angle that is found by adding or subtracting the multiple of $2\pi$ if the given angle is in radian or $360^{\circ}$ if the angle is given in degree measure. What is your answer for $1 km+10 cm$? You must write either 100010 cm or 1.00001 km right? $110011_2+50$ definitely make sense that we are adding a binary number with a decimal number but you convert before you conclude. $\frac{\pi}{5}+360^{\circ}$ also means a coterminal angle but not the angle is supposed to mean. Just a unitary problem.

Comment: No "answer" is needed for $1km + 10cm$. It is a perfectly valid length. $1km + 10cm$ is $1km + 10cm$, just like $x + y$ is $x + y$, even if you know that $y = \frac{x}{10000}$